# How do I get a Discord member count on my website?

Tags: discord

I'm using Discord.js for the bot that moniters the member count of 7 guilds, but I want to export that number to a website. Any ideas?

Comment: The sum of member count of all guilds, or a list of member counts? Either way, it's as simple as finding the member count via discordjs and exposing that data on an API route for your website. You'll also want to take into consideration caching: how often do you want the count to update? Every time someone joins a server? Every time someone reloads their page? Once every 5 minutes? After someone reloads, store it and use that number for 5 minutes until another request comes in after that time has elapsed?

Comment: To gather the member count im using `message.client.guilds.cache.map((g) => g.memberCount).reduce((a, c) => a + c)`. I want it to update every 10 minutes or so.